# Saving and downloading not working on Chrome OS - Ubuntu dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, google-chrome, downloads, chromebook

I have an Acer C300 Chromebook with a dual boot Chrome OS - Ubuntu System, However since installing Ubuntu I cannot save or download anything on Chrome OS. Saving and downloads still work when booting on Ubuntu. Any suggestions?

Comment: What happens when you try to download?  The download simply fails immediately?

Comment: nothing, literally nothing, it wont even attempt a download, it just wont respond to download links or save buttons

Comment: anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I am the original poster of this question. I have no idea still what was causing this issue, however i deleted my chroot system, then installed the ubuntu again. it seems to have solved the issue.